# Integrating AWS CloudSearch with .NET Core and AWS RDS

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudsearch

I am searching for the integration of AWS CloudSearch with .NET Core and AWS RDS but I couldn't find much help online.

I have two challenges:

1. Is it possible to integrate AWS RDS with AWS CloudSearch?
2. Any guides for integrating AWS CloudSearch with .NET Core for updating document batches?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to integrate AWS RDS with AWS CloudSearch?

If you mean using data stored within RDS, for searching - then **yes** as per [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/faqs/):

> A search service requires that your documents already be stored somewhere, whether it's in files of a file system, data in Amazon S3, or records in an Amazon DynamoDB or Amazon RDS instance.

---

> Any guides for integrating AWS CloudSearch with .NET Core for updating document batches?

The official AWS .NET SDK V3 docs for [`UploadDocumentsRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudSearchDomain/TUploadDocumentsRequest.html) should be a good starting point (related API docs: [`documents/batch`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/documents-batch-resource.html)).